# onListItemClick when extends ActionBarActivity

Tags: android

```
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```

I want to add actionbar to my app, but extending to ActionBarActivity instead of ListViewActivity i can't manage onListItemClick.

Here is my code. No error but click on list item doesn't works.

```
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
.....
public class XXX extends ActionBarActivity {
.....
ListView getListView() {
    if (mListView == null) {
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }
    return mListView;
}

protected void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}

protected ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
    ListAdapter adapter = getListView().getAdapter();
    if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
        return ((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
    } else {
        return adapter;
    }}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    getListView().getOnItemClickListener().onItemClick(l, v, position, id);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mLv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Don't forget the imports:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

Comment: OK! I put it on OnCreate! Works!

Answer (score 0):

for that follow below steps:

1. delete all extra-values folders except values
2. Delete Menu folders
3. Delete style tag in side application tag in your manifest file.
4. remove extra libraries related to android.support.v7 in project properties.
5. Now you can change  ActionBarActivity  into ListViewActivity.

I think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the class you dont have:

```
implements onitemclicklistener
```

and you don't say to a listview the listener. Try this:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

don't remember to add unimplementeds methods.